# How to save stream without metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to divide the file into streams using map, but the problem is that the metadata is copied to the stream. How can I explicitly specify not to copy metainformation into the stream?

I try this:

```
ffmpeg -i 'movie.mp4' -map_metadata -1 -map 0:1 -c copy audio.m4a
```

Answer (score 0):

For information about chapters there is a special parameter -map_chapters

This solved my problem:

```
ffmpeg -i 'movie.mp4' -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 -map 0:1 -c copy audio.m4a
```